# Javascript and Jquery No Conflict function on Link Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am needing to run jQuery in no conflict mode. I have a link that when clicked opens a dialog function.  In the console I receive an error which states - 'Uncaught ReferenceError: show_appeal_dialog is not defined'

Here is the link:

```
<a style='color:blue;' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='show_appeal_dialog(33558)'>Denied</a>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function(){
function show_appeal_dialog(ponumber){
$j("#appeal_dialog").dialog({
        title: 'Appeal Notes',
        modal: true,
        width: 660,
        height:250,
        open: function() {
            $j(this).html(ponumber);
        },
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
            $j(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
});
}
});
```

I have tried to replace the $j with just jQuery and also changed the var $j(function) and also removing the $j(function) and just using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you have defined the `show_appeal_dialog` in document ready handler scope.

You should get rid of ugly inline click handler like

```js
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function() {
  function show_appeal_dialog(ponumber) {
    $j("#appeal_dialog")
      .html(ponumber)
      .dialog({
        title: 'Appeal Notes',
        modal: true,
        width: 660,
        height: 250,
        autoOpen: true,
        buttons: {
          Ok: function() {
            $j(this).dialog("close");
          }
        }
      });
  }

  $j(".anchor").click(function() {
    show_appeal_dialog($j(this).data("popnumber"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<a class="anchor" data-popnumber="33558" style='color:blue;' href='#' >Denied</a>
<div id="appeal_dialog" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because scoping is the issue. You wrap it in a document ready call and that makes the function not available in global scope. It has nothing to do with no conflict mode.

Either get rid of the `$j(function(){` wrapping the function or hook up events wthout the inline onclick attribute.